# will using file_get_contents to retrieve sql queries cause any significant bottleneck

Tags: php, sql

I have a *fairly large* **MySQL** query within one of my **PHP** scripts (about 45 lines long).

This large block of **SQL** makes the actual **PHP** class almost unreadable and I'm considering moving it to its own `.sql` file and just retrieving it using `file_get_contents`, like so:

```
$sql = file_get_contents("/path/to/query.sql");
$params = array(1, 2, 3);

$query = $this->_conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($params);
```

The issue is, this will probably be *the most called script* by my user base and I don't want a huge bottleneck slowing down my application.

So, is using `file_get_contents` to retrieve a large query bad practice? Is it slower? Are there any noticeable downsides to doing things this way?

If it isn't a good idea, are there any alternatives to this approach?

Comment: If someone accidentally knows the "/path/to/query.sql"... what can happen ?

Comment: @KenLee Would be hidden, outside of the public scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track to want to increase code readability by pulling in a separate file, however `file_get_contents` is going to incur additional overhead.

A better way of doing this is with `include`. This allows you to insert some code from another file into your PHP file, keeping your code clean and eliminating the need for `file_get_contents`.

Here's an example:

```
/* sqlFunctions.php */

function getSQL() {
    return "SELECT * FROM table";
}
```

```
/* index.php */

include "sqlFunctions.php";

...

// use the sql code in whatever way you execute it; $mysqli->query is simply an example here
$mysqli->query(getSQL());
```